# Querying for commentator repo and poster repo for different values of the comment ID (stored in a table) in SEDE

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I modify the following query

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN U.Id = P.OwnerUserId THEN 'Poster' ELSE 'Commenter' END AS [User],
  U.Id AS [User Link],
  U.Reputation AS [User Rep]
FROM Comments AS C
INNER JOIN Posts AS P
  ON P.Id = C.PostId
INNER JOIN Users AS U
  ON U.Id IN (P.OwnerUserId, C.UserId)
WHERE C.Id = ##CommentId:int##
```

Such that CommentId : is each row in the Table containing only constant values of comment ID's. Particularly I want to iterate this query for each row of the table :

```
       Comment ID <-- Table 
        3421105
        1041243
        8118167
        3073399
        712153
        1877813
        834036
        6233902
        7762628
        7944447
        724240
        3256044
        3041609
        6206686
        7825212
        6143469
        5818437
        5209319
        4358493
        7697908
        2157522
```

Here is the link where the query can be run :

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/180387/name-and-rep-of-commenter-and-op-for-comment-id#resultSets

I am new to SQL queries, if the moderators or high reputed users feel that this is a trivial question , I would really appreciate if you could direct me to similar questions.

The output result should look like :

```
  COMMENTOR REPO |  POSTER REPO  |   COMMENT ID

    ..                 ..              ..
    ..                 ..              ..
```

Comment: Well, I don't understand what it is that you want. And it doesn't help that your output example actually hides the values that should go in every column

Comment: @Lamak : Does that make any sense ?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(Id int PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO @T VALUES 
(3421105), (1041243), (8118167), (3073399), (712153 ), (1877813), (834036 ), 
(6233902), (7762628), (7944447), (724240 ), (3256044), (3041609), (6206686), 
(7825212), (6143469), (5818437), (5209319), (4358493), (7697908), (2157522)

SELECT
  CU.Reputation AS [COMMENTER REPO],
  PU.Reputation AS [POSTER REPO],
  C.Id AS [COMMENT ID]
FROM Comments AS C
  INNER JOIN Posts AS P
    ON P.Id = C.PostId
  INNER JOIN Users AS PU
    ON PU.Id = P.OwnerUserId
  INNER JOIN Users AS CU
    ON CU.Id = C.UserId
WHERE C.Id IN (SELECT T.Id FROM @T AS T)
```

[Data exchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/181801/name-and-rep-of-commenter-and-op-for-comment-id)